# What I can use place of appcfg.py download / update for google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, appcfg

I was generally using the code below to update my project files.

appcfg.py -A project_name -V 1 update c:\myapp\

But now I'm getting an error. That I am not authorized by cred_policy. As a result of my research, I realized that appcfg.py is no longer used. How can I update my project in the easiest way right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gcloud app deploy` command instead of `appcfg.py`.

It would look something like this: `gcloud app deploy c:\myapp\app.yaml --project= project_name`

Follow the below link for more information.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrating-from-appcfg-to-gcloud